# Is it possible to NOT recreate activity after locking the phone manually?

Tags: java, android

I was trying to make simple openGL ES application(currently learning), when I lock the phone or clicking to return button, onStop triggering itself and when i unlock or open the app from tasks, the activity re-creating itself and the triangle(from android studio opengl es beginner documents) corrupting.

I have tried to log when app triggers onCreate:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Log.w("ONCREATE", "Hello, something happened here.");

   getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
     mSurface = new SurfaceView(this);
     setContentView(mSurface);
}
```

I want my application to not re-create the activity(I want it to create when actually starts, no more).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot prevent an Activity from being recreated when the screen turns off or the user homes out.

I recommend you start your journey through Android via the [official Android Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals) to understand the lifecycle of an Android application in the constrained environment of a Linux OS running on a constrained device (your Phone/Tablet).

You should stop rendering/release your OpenGL surfaces when the activity/application is stopped, to stop using user resources and recreate it once you get back.